# Python backtracking maze really slow

Tags: python, maze, recursive-backtracking

*check the edit*,
I wrote some code while watching The Coding Train on youtube.. the maze backtracking generator. The youtuber wrote the code in javascript and I tried to understand the code while writing in python. It seems he had to change the framerate because his program was so fast just to see the generating part. While mine after some 10ish squares it was already so slow.
It cant be an hardware problem, I've got an i5-4690K CPU and a good matching GPU, it must be something in the code! But I can't find what it is.

I rewatched the episodes so I could see what was wrong, but it seems I wrote everything just fine.

```py
from tkinter import *
import math
import random
import time

# initialization canvas
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, bg="#333333")
canvas.pack()

# some global variables
w = 40;
cols = math.floor(int(canvas["width"])/w)
rows = math.floor(int(canvas["height"])/w)
grid = []
current = None

class Cell():
    line_color = "#AAAAAA"
    visited_color = "green"
    visited = False
    rectangle = None

    def __init__(self, i, j):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j
        self.wall = [True, True, True, True] # top , right, bottom, left

    def __repr__(self):
        return "({}, {})".format(self.i, self.j)

    def draw_lines(self):
        x = self.i*w
        y = self.j*w

        if self.visited :
            self.rectangle = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+w, y+w, fill="purple", outline="")
            canvas.update()

        if self.wall[0]:
            canvas.create_line(x, y, x+w, y, fill=self.line_color)
        else:
            canvas.create_line(x, y, x+w, y, fill="purple")
        if self.wall[1]:
            canvas.create_line(x+w, y, x+w, y+w, fill=self.line_color)
        else:
            canvas.create_line(x+w, y, x+w, y+w, fill="purple")
        if self.wall[2]:
            canvas.create_line(x, y+w, x+w, y+w, fill=self.line_color)
        else:
            canvas.create_line(x, y+w, x+w, y+w, fill="purple")
        if self.wall[3]:
            canvas.create_line(x, y, x, y+w, fill=self.line_color)
        else:
            canvas.create_line(x, y, x, y+w, fill="purple")

    def checkNeighbors(self):
        neighbors = []
        top = None
        bottom = None
        left = None
        right = None
        if index(self.i, self.j-1) != -1:
            top = grid[index(self.i, self.j-1)]

        if index(self.i, self.j+1) != -1:
            bottom = grid[index(self.i, self.j+1)]

        if index(self.i-1, self.j) != -1:
            left = grid[index(self.i-1, self.j)]

        if index(self.i+1, self.j) != -1:
            right = grid[index(self.i+1, self.j)]

        if top is not None and top.visited is False:
            neighbors.append(top)
        if right is not None and right.visited is False:
            neighbors.append(right)
        if bottom is not None and bottom.visited is False:
            neighbors.append(bottom)
        if left is not None and left.visited is False:
            neighbors.append(left)

        if len(neighbors) > 0:
            r = random.randint(0, len(neighbors)-1)
            return neighbors[r]
        else:
            return None

def removeWalls(a, b):
    x = a.i - b.i
    y = a.j - b.j

    if x != 0:
        if x == 1:
            a.wall[3] = False
            b.wall[1] = False
        else:
            a.wall[1] = False
            b.wall[3] = False

    if y != 0:
        if y == 1:
            a.wall[0] = False
            b.wall[2] = False
        else:
            a.wall[2] = False
            b.wall[0] = False

def index(i, j):
    if j < 0 or j > rows - 1 or i < 0 or i > cols - 1:
        return -1
    return j + i * cols

def setup():
    global current
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            cell = Cell(i, j)
            grid.append(cell)
    current = grid[0]

next_one = None
def draw():
    global current
    global next_one
    stack = []
    almost = False
    while True:
        current.visited = True
        for cell in grid:
            cell.draw_lines()
        next_one = current.checkNeighbors()
        if next_one:
            stack.append(current)
            removeWalls(current, next_one)
            current = next_one
        elif len(stack) > 0:
            cell = stack.pop()
            current = cell

for cell in grid:
    print(cell.visited)

setup()
draw()


root.mainloop()
```

I'm sorry to put all the code, but I think all of it is relevant for what comes to performance, haven't put any useful comments, sorry I'm trying to become a better programmer and change that bad habit

**BIG EDIT:**
I tested to just draw my maze once I finished calculating it, and it takes less than a second, so I figure it has to be with the amount of widgets (lines) I'm creating..? How could I minimize the widgets so I could see the maze being created like I wanted to?

Comment: You may want to profile your application. This will show you where exactly you spend more time than expected. See the ``cprofile`` and ``vmprof`` packages, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You draw lines even if they didn't change. Instead, draw only the changed cells.

Besides, you have endless loop. Even if stack contains no more elements, you don't stop. Here you should break the loop.

Here is an improvement:

```
def draw():
    for cell in grid:
        cell.draw_lines()
    global current
    global next_one
    stack = []
    almost = False
    while True:
        current.visited = True
        next_one = current.checkNeighbors()
        if next_one:
            stack.append(current)
            removeWalls(current, next_one)
            current.draw_lines()
            next_one.draw_lines()
            current = next_one
        elif len(stack) > 0:
            cell = stack.pop()
            current = cell
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the problem, it works perfectly now :) !